# Python : Counting execution of recursive call

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, counting

I am using Euler problems to test my understanding as I learn Python 3.x. After I cobble together a working solution to each problem, I find the posted solutions very illuminating and I can "absorb" new ideas after I have struggled myself. I am working on Euler 024 and I am trying a recursive approach. Now, in no ways do I believe my approach is the most efficient or most elegant, however, I successfully generate a full set of permutations, increasing in value (because I start with a sorted tuple) - which is one of the outputs I want. In addition, in order to find the millionth in the list (which is the other output I want, but can't yet get) I am trying to count how many there are each time I create a permutation and that's where I get stuck. In other words what I want to do is count the number of recursive calls each time I reach the base case, i.e. a completed permutation, not the total number of recursive calls.  I have found on StackOverflow some very clear examples of counting number of executions of recursive calls but I am having no luck applying the idea to my code. Essentially my problems in my attempts so far are about "passing back" the count of the "completed" permutation using a return statement. I think I need to do that because the way my for loop creates the "stem" and "tail" tuples. At a high level, either I can't get the counter to increment (so it always comes out as "1" or "5") or the "nested return" just terminates the code after the first permutation is found, depending on where I place the return. Can anyone help insert the counting into my code?

First the "counting" code I found in SO that I am trying to use:

```
def recur(n, count=0):
    if n == 0:
        return "Finished count %s" % count

    return recur(n-1, count+1)

print(recur(15))
```

Next is my permutation code with no counting in it. I have tried lots of approaches, but none of them work. So the following has no "counting" in it, just a comment at which point in the code I believe the counter needs to be incremented.

```
#
# euler 024 : Lexicographic permutations
#
import time
startTime= time.time()
#
def splitList(listStem,listTail):

    for idx in range(0,len(listTail)):
        tempStem =((listStem) + (listTail[idx],))
        tempTail = ((listTail[:idx]) + (listTail[1+idx:]))

        splitList(tempStem,tempTail)
    if len(listTail) ==0:
        #
        # I want to increment counter only when I am here
        #
        print("listStem=",listStem,"listTail=",listTail)

#
inStem = ()
#inTail = ("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9")
inTail = ("0","1","2","3")

testStem = ("0","1")
testTail = ("2","3","4","5")

splitList(inStem,inTail)
#
print('Code execution duration : ',time.time() - startTime,' seconds')
```

Thanks in advance,

Clive

Comment: What output do you get? What are you expecting? Just to clarify, your program lexically sorts strings? What's your input?

Comment: To clarify: I will update my question to make clearer:" I successfully generate a full set of permutations, increasing in value (because I start with a sorted tuple)". - which is one  result I want. "In addition, in order to find the millionth in the list" - which I need but can't currently get.

Comment: My (test) input tuples are "inTail" and inStem. I switched from lists to immutable tuples because trying to use list methods .append and .remove I lost track of where I was in the list. As in the question, I am sure there is a more elegant methods to generate the permutations but I have something that generates a full set and at the moment I am just trying to add the counting. My focus on the moment is to understand the counting so I can find an approach to counting that I can apply in other , similar situations

Comment: So, all you want to do is understand the number of recursive calls made by the time you reach your base case. Okay, I hope you'll find my answer addresses that satisfactorily.

Comment: @COLDSPEED "So, all you want to do is understand the number of recursive calls made by the time you reach your base case. " Exactly - well put! I will update my question to use your wording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seems you've understood the basic problem but just want to understand how the recursion is happening, all you need to do is pass a variable that tells you at what point of the call stack you're in. You can add a 3rd argument to your function, and increment it with each recursive call:

```
def splitList(listStem, listTail, count):   
    for idx in range(0,len(listTail)):
        ...
        splitList(tempStem, tempTail, count)

    if len(listTail) == 0:
        count[0] += 1
        print('Count:', count)
        ...
```

Now, call this function like this (same as before):

```
splitList(inStem, inTail, [0])
```

Comment: @COLDSPEED. Thanks for your prompt response. I will try to clarify a bit more - and update my question again. I have tried that keyword parameter approach, but in my code I am trying only to count only completed permutations, not the number of recursive calls - which is why my comment is after the len(list Tail) - my question is probably misleading on that.

Comment: @CliveLong Pardon me, I'm a little rusty with lex sort. Does the case of a completed permutation arise more than once?

Comment: @COLDSPEED. Not quite sure I understand your question but for example when I run using data: inStem = (), inTail = ("0","1","2","3"), I get 4! (24) permutations displayed starting: listStem= ('0', '1', '2', '3') listTail= (), ending listStem= ('3', '2', '1', '0') listTail= (), which is what I want, all permutation in lexicographical (?) order, with no duplicates.

Comment: @CliveLong I got it. I've edited my answer with a slightly dirty solution. I'm wrapping the count inside a list, since lists are passed by reference, I can access and modify the count in the `if` which I couldn't do before. Do note how the function is called.

Comment: @COLDSPEED TaDa ! It lives ! It lives ! What is the key Idea I should be taking away from this? Thanks. Extra: My code is horribly slow. I will be interested in alternate solutions on the Euler website.

Comment: @CliveLong The general understanding is the succinctness of recursion hides its complexity. :) You should consider iteration in most approaches because it is a lot cheaper space wise (and in many more cases, easier to code). As far as understanding how the recursion works, you should probably be debugging each step for clearer insight, rather than just the base case.

Comment: @COLDSPEED Thanks again. I had believed that recursion is considered a "good thing" but I understand, and have seen, how easy it is to run out of resources when executing. I did have "print" statements plastered all over the for loop to understand how the count was being incremented - but it wasn't being incremented. I am slightly relieved to hear that debugging recursion can be more challenging than debugging iteration.

Comment: @CliveLong No problem, and thanks for the good question. Not often do you find users genuinely attempting to understand a problem. Rather you have people abusing the site like a code sweatshop and behaving like they're entitled to your help.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write generator for this?
Then you can just stop on `n`th item ("drop while i < n").

Mine solution is using `itertools`, but you can use your own permutations generator. Just `yield` next sequence member instead of printing it.

```
from itertools import permutations as perm, dropwhile as dw
print(''.join(dw(
    lambda x: x[0]<1000000, 
    enumerate(perm('0123456789'),1)
).__next__()[1]))
```